# Discord.js creating ticket when pressed reaction on embed not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a ticket system for my discord bot but I can't figure out why excatly this part of code isn't working. I'm using discord.js v13.

So basically I have made this embed with reaction which is meant to be pressed and bot creates new text channel.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a81KV.png)

And here is my code for creating new ticket after pressing reaction on embed:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if(user.partial) await user.fetch();
    if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
    if(reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();

    if(user.bot) return;

    const ticketid = await settings.get(`${reaction.message.guild.id}-ticket`);

    if(!ticketid) return;

    if(reaction.message.id == ticketid && reaction.emoji.name == '') {
        reaction.users.remove(user);

        reaction.message.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${user.username}`, {
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: user.id,
                    allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL"]
                },
                {
                    id: reaction.message.guild.roles.everyone,
                    deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"]
                }
            ],
            type: 'text'
        }).then(async channel => {
            channel.send({ embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setTitle("Sveicināts `<@${user.id}>`!").setDescription("Lai saņemtu palīdzību raksti šajā kanālā.").setColor("FFFA33")] })
        })
    }
});
```

Can someone please help me, I've been trying to make this work for days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use collector
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collector
or check the guide
https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-reaction-collector